# How to increment current time?

Tags: java, android

I am getting date in the format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm aa. I need to increment this by one hour. How can I do this?

example code ..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(previous_time);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
previous_time = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.addHours(date, 1);